# comprehendible vs comprehensible

Tags: word-choice, able-ible

Just got into a debate at work whether *comprehendible* is a word.  It appears as I type this that *comprehensible* is preferred in Firefox's dictionary.  However, when I used Outlook's spellchecker it changed *comprehendable* to *comprehendible*.

So which is it?

Comment: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehendible

Comment: http://www.audioenglish.net/dictionary/comprehendible.htm

Comment: Wow, awesome...so I have no answer...it appears to be a word according to a couple "clearly authoritative sources".  However, http://oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/?region=uk&q=comprehendible does not exist...so how is this "definitively and permanently answered by a single link"?

Comment: The OED does have the word "comprehendible" (with another form "comprehendable"). However, it's marked "rare."

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/90426/2085

Comment: I can't tell from the definitions when you'd use one over the other. I'm currently favouring 'comprehendible' as 'comprehensible' can be confused with 'comprehensive' which has a very different meaning. Is it okay to reopen and edit the question to focus on usage differences (if any)?