# "Extensible" vs. "extendible"

Tags: word-choice, differences, adjectives, suffixes, consonants

Where does the adjective form *extensible* come from and does it connote anything different than *extendible*? What's the difference, if any, between the two?

Comment: ...additionally, is there a difference between extendible and extendable?

Comment: [Related post on Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/87258/difference-between-extensible-programming-and-extendible-programming)

Comment: -1 for not showing any research.

Comment: Historical comparison: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=extendable%2Cextensible&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cextendable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cextensible%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @MattE.Эллен ... I'm pretty sure you understood the question just as well with or without research...

Comment: and what research would he have used?

If he did any research, there would not be a point in not only asking, but posting the question; he'd've had his answer.

Comment: Which is exactly the point, @DaMaxContent.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен if everyone did research, then there would be no point in any asking question on this site now would there?

Comment: Yes. For when the research you've done doesn't answer the question you have. We're not asking for doctoral theses, just look in a dictionary.

Comment: @AspWri88 There's some good answers here (since 2012). How about selecting one as the right answer?

Comment: @SF. See also [Difference between "extendable" and "extensible"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/131628/4980) on English Language Learners. [The answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/275211/4980) seems interesting: "inherently extensible" vs "extendable by snapping on additional lengths of hose".

Answer (score 105):

It appears that I probably draw a finer distinction here than others may, but the good thing is that for those that say the two are interchangeable, my usage will seem unremarkable, and for those that care, my usage will seem consistent.

I use *extendable* in cases where it means the opposite of retractable.  In other words, a telescoping wand is extendable, the legs of my camera tripod are extendable.

I use *extensible* when I mean that the functionality of something may be increased or enhanced by the addition of an extension- an add-on module or component.  My web browser is extensible because I can add an Adobe Flash extension which allows me to view flash content.  I think it would sound a bit odd to talk about my web-browser being *extendable*.

Comment: So, if you can buy special attachments for your tripod that will allow you to mount different equipment upon it, then I suppose you'd have an extensible, extendable tripod.

Comment: You may be right.  I like your nuance.

Comment: In this usage, extendable seems to have a perspective from the outside in, whereas extensible seems to be from inside out.

Comment: This distinction reminds of *farther* vs. *further*.

Comment: Sad that you thought about Flash. Good that you didn't say you added that extension.

Comment: @0xc0de - Well it *was* 2012.... :-)

Comment: Best answer when factoring in software development terminology.

Comment: I like this: _extendable_ means it can be made bigger by itself; _extensible_ means it can be made bigger by adding something (an extension).

Comment: @CSJ, fantastic(ally succint) summary, the best so far!

Answer (score 31):

There are lots and lots of these.  They usually came to us that way straight from Latin, and seldom mean anything different from each other.  One may be more rare than another, though.

- comprehendible, comprehensible
- corrodable, corrodible, corrosible
- defendable, defensible
- deridable, derisible
- dividable, divisible
- evadable, evasible
- expandable, expansible
- explodable, explosible
- extendible, extensible
- inevadible, inevasible
- invadable, invasible
- offendable, offensible
- persuadable, persuasible
- protrudable, protrusible
- reprehendable, reprehensible
- rescindable, rescindible
- revisable, revisible
- subdividable, subdivisible
- suspendible, suspensible
- undefendable, undefensible
- undividable, undivisible

Comment: hopefully no one mistakenly confuses sensible and sendable :)

Comment: if it is not sensible it is not sendable

Comment: When spelling in English couldn't get any easier

Answer (score 3):

The Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style (2000) says:

> Other variant adjectives, though, are merely duplicative. Typical examples are *extendable*, *extendible*, and *extensible*. The first of these is now prevalent in AmE (though labeled obsolete in the OED). *Extensible* was, through the mid-20th century, the most common form, but today it trails *extendable* by a substantial margin, while *extendible* continues to appear infrequently. Writers and editors ought to settle on the most firmly established form--*extendable*, which is as well formed as the variants--and trouble their minds with weightier matters.

https://books.google.com/books?id=z_VmtjAU01YC&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4

Answer (score 2):

The *Oxford Dictionary for Writers & Editors* says:

> *extendible*, not -*able*, but in general use *extensible* not -*able*

Comment: And the *Wiktionary* has an [entry for *extendable*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/extendable#English).

Answer (score 1):

In WordReference site, its given that extensible means capable of being extended.

> **extend**/ɪkˈstend/
>   *verb*
>
> 1 make larger or longer in space or time.
>      • occupy a specified area or continue for a specified distance.
>
> 2 hold (something) out towards someone.
>      • offer or make available.
>
> 3 (extend to) be applicable to.
>
> 4 strain or exert to the utmost.
>
> – derivatives
>   extendability *noun*,
>   extendable *adjective*,
>   extendibility *noun*,
>   extendible *adjective*,
>   extensibility *noun*,
>   **extensible *adjective*.**

Also want to add some info got from another useful source,

Extensible seems to me to indicate stretchability whereas extendable suggests an opening out or lengthening. An elastic band is extensible, i.e.: it can be stretched, whereas my lunch hour is extendable, i.e.: it can be added to, but an hour is an hour and cannot be stretched. There is also *extensile* which seems to mean the same as *extensible*.

Comment: It would be good if you could cite the source from which you quote.

Answer (score 1):

I use the terms as Jim does in the context of Computer Science. In a computer program, if I add subroutines or blocks it is extendable - I can add more blocks. If the program is extensible, the individual blocks may be made more complex by modification, usually adding flexibility.

Comment: "made more complex by modification, usually adding flexibility". You might make them more complex, or you might simplify them. A technique used is to add flexibility, but flexibility can be a characteristic of extensible code. In short - I think your answer can be improved