# When to use attributive nouns vs. deverbal adjectives

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm not sure if I have the title correct, but I am trying to figure out how to determine whether to use a noun form as an adjective or a verb form as an adjective.

For example:

1) Is it an extension leg or an extending leg?

2) Is it a stabilization wing or a stabilizing wing?

Is this a case-by-case thing? Does it depend upon context? I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: An _extending leg_ can be made longer; an _extension leg_ sounds as though it supports an extension of a table or similar. I'm not sure about the wing.

Comment: Thanks Kate. From your answer, I realized that "extension leg" fits better with my original concept of an extension of a leg. Another description for "extending leg" might be a telescoping leg. This would be a different thing. Perhaps the second example is the better one to focus on because I am trying to figure out a general principle for using a noun (e.g., stabilization) as an adjective vs. a verb (e.g., stabilizing). I don't think the second example has the same caveat.

Comment: Stabilization wing would be a part that always serves the purpose of stabilizing.  That is it is sole or primary function within a machine.  A stabilizing wing could be ANY part serves to stabilize.  It wasn't necessarily designed that way.

Comment: *Stabilizing wing* could as well be self reflexive, essentially a wing that has the tendency to stay stable, the stabilty of the flying thing being secondary. Latin would have *stabilisator* for the agent sense. Germanic has lost or coallesced many such morphemes, substituted different foreign morphemes later on (Latin, French, Greek for a start) and created new ones in the mix in an attempt to reinvent the wing. It's rocket science and it is a wonder that it flies at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a technical translator, I can (almost) assure you this is a case-per-case issue.

In the case of the leg, "extendable" might be the best option (see ["Extensible" vs. "extendible"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90426/extensible-vs-extendible)) to mean that it **can be** extended. "extension leg" sounds like a leg that **provides an extension** for something else, like "extension cord".

In the case of the wing, in technical English "stabilizer" tends to be the most usual form: "stabilizer wing".

Note: In my opinion, the title of your question would be more accurate if it said: "Attributive nouns vs deverbal adjectives".

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense - and subject of post changed accordingly.

Comment: *rebel leader* vs *rebellion leader*, or *bed pan* vs *bedside pan* would be a case of attributive noun vs ..? *extension* jointly fits that pattern. Whatever OP had in mind, there is no consistent grammatical paradigm. The world and consequently the descriptions are way to complex for that, I agree.